# Who are good suppliers of .NET 4 Hosted Virtual Private Servers ? (May 2010)

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, .net-4.0

I'm looking for a supplier for hosting a Virtual server, running Windows Server 2008 (R2 ideally) <strike>and .NET 4 to run an internet facing ASP.NET web application</strike>.

I'd also like to be able to remote desktop onto it, and install other apps as necessary, including other websites as and when.

I'm based in the UK, so a UK based supplier would be great. I was looking at [Fasthosts](http://www.fasthosts.com), but having researched them a bit more, they look like a bad idea.

Comment: In my observation, questions about hosting attract LOTS of hosting ad spammers. Nearly every answer gets marked as a spam and deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I feel a bit odd suggesting this, but if it is a virtual server for which you can logon to (e.g. Administer) then surely you can install .Net Framework 4.0 onto it yourself...

therefore you just require a virtual server that most hosting companies offer...

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. I'll amend the question...